# Use rating difference as the match criterion for pgn-extract

Tags: pgn-extract

Is it possible to use the rating **difference** between the players as a match criterium for pgn-extract?

If not, then this looks to me like a nice new feature.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't currently, but - as the author of pgn-extract - I am always happy to entertain ideas for new features if you wish to contact me about them.

Answer (score 0):

I had contact with David. He has implemented the feature and I have tested it succesfully. It will be in the next release!